# Defining function to open an Excel file (openpyxl) and save as a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a typical method that I use to pull data from an Excel file into a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as op

path = r'thisisafilepath\filename.xlsx'
book = op.load_workbook(filename=path, data_only=True)
tab = book['sheetname']
data = tab.values
columns = next(data)[0:]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

I'm trying to define this method as a function to make the code simpler/more readable.

I have tried the following:

```
def openthis(path, sheet):
    book = op.load_workbook(filename=path, data_only=True)
    tab = book[sheet]
    data = tab.values
    columns = next(data)[0:]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    return df
```

When I then call openthis() the output is a printed version of the DataFrame in my console, but no variable has actually been created for me to work with.

What am I missing? Also, is there a way to define what the DataFrame variable is called when it is produced?

Comment: Can’t see any error here. How’re you calling this function?  example - df = openthis(“path”, “sheet”) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your actual implementation of calling it but I'm guessing that you didn't assign the output to a variable.

Notice in your function `return df`.

This statement means when you call openthis() it outputs a variable. Unless you assign that output to a local variable, its gone forever.

Try this

`df = openthis(some_arguments)`